# Create various from Wordlist

Tags: c#

I want to create a password list.

So far, it works but my list contains only words like `D?t1g3+T%J`.

Now I want to create words with more sense.
I have a List with words like **Banana**, **Desk** and so on.
How is it possible to change randomly the spelling, add numbers and special characters?

For example:

> "Banana" -> "baNana123"

Comment: What you're actually trying to do? Why you need these passwords?

Comment: We are doing a penetration test in school.

Comment: Is "we" the school IT or you :-0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have just come up with this.

```
string foo = "banana";
            List<string> chars = new List<string>();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string newPassword = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; i++)
            {
                chars.Add(foo[i].ToString());
            }
            foreach (var boo in chars)
            {
                var randomNum = rnd.Next(0, 2);
                Debug.WriteLine(randomNum);
                if (randomNum == 0)
                {
                    newPassword = newPassword + boo.ToUpper();
                }
                else
                {
                    newPassword = newPassword + boo.ToLower();
                }
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(newPassword);
```

What it does:  1)strips the string, in my case "banana" into individual characters

2) for every character program generates randomly 1, or 0. Base on that I just simply convert to lower, or upper case.

All you have to do is to feed the algorithm with strings. And to the adding numbers at the end you can do something like this I quess.

```
int howMany = rnd.Next(1, 20); //1 to 19 numbers, you can set that manually
            for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
            {
                newPassword = newPassword + rnd.Next(0, 10);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(newPassword);
```

Outcome last run for me: BanANA6469242684